# How to Access Private Github Repo File (.csv) in Python using Pandas or Requests

Tags: python, pandas, git, csv, private

I had to switch my public Github repository to private and cannot access files, not with access tokens that I was able to with the public Github repo.

I can access my private repo's CSV with curl:
'''
curl -s https://{token}@raw.githubusercontent.com/username/repo/master/file.csv

'''

However, I want to access this information in my python file. When the repo was public I could simply use:
'''
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/repo/master/file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, error_bad_lines=False)

'''

This no longer works now that the repo is private, and I cannot find a work around to download this CSV in python instead of pulling from terminal.

If I try:
'''
requests.get(https://{token}@raw.githubusercontent.com/username/repo/master/file.csv)
'''
I get a 404 response, which is basically the same thing that is happening with the pd.read_csv(). If I click on the raw file I see that a temporary token is created and the URL is:
'''
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/username/repo/master/file.csv?token=TEMPTOKEN
'''
Is there a way to attach my permanent private access token so that I can always pull this data from github?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what ended up working for me - leaving it here if anyone runs into the same issue. Thanks for the help!

```
    import json, requests, urllib, io

    user='my_github_username'
    pao='my_pao'

    github_session = requests.Session()
    github_session.auth = (user, pao)

    # providing raw url to download csv from github
    csv_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/csv_name.csv'

    download = github_session.get(csv_url).content
    downloaded_csv = pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO(download.decode('utf-8')), error_bad_lines=False)
```

Comment: Hey so I am working with a similar private repo (.csv) file and want to know of any ways I can like edit the file hosted on github apart from read it. Intuitively I assume I should be able to edit the data since I can read the data, but I can't arrive at a solution.

Comment: You can make edits to the file, but you would then have to commit and push you changes to the repository. For you can just use git commands

Comment: This also worked for me, as I created a fine-grained token via GitHub and used it in the requests. It also works with the classic token. Thanks, @everwitt7

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you may download CSV file in Python instead of pulling from terminal. To achieve that you may use GitHub API v3 with 'requests' and 'io' modules assistance. Reproducible example below.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
from io import StringIO

# Create CSV file
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2,size=10_000).reshape(1_000,10))
df.to_csv('filename.csv') 

# -> now upload file to private github repo

# define parameters for a request
token = 'paste-there-your-personal-access-token' 
owner = 'repository-owner-name'
repo = 'repository-name-where-data-is-stored'
path = 'filename.csv'

# send a request
r = requests.get(
    'https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{path}'.format(
    owner=owner, repo=repo, path=path),
    headers={
        'accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3.raw',
        'authorization': 'token {}'.format(token)
            }
    )

# convert string to StringIO object
string_io_obj = StringIO(r.text)

# Load data to df
df = pd.read_csv(string_io_obj, sep=",", index_col=0)

# optionally write df to CSV
df.to_csv("file_name_02.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

This way is working for me really good:

```
    def _github(url: str, mode: str = "private"):
        url = url.replace("/blob/", "/")
        url = url.replace("/raw/", "/")
        url = url.replace("github.com/", "raw.githubusercontent.com/")

        if mode == "public":
            return requests.get(url)
        else:
            token = os.getenv('GITHUB_TOKEN', '...')
            headers = {
                'Authorization': f'token {token}',
                'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3.raw'}
            return requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: But how to use this function? Please elaborate on that.

Comment: working like charm @Sachin for your answer... use it like just 
1. Get the personal access token from gihub
2. at the token variable paste your token 
3. call the function response = _github(url=github_file_url.json)
4. response.text for getting output data

Answer (score 1):

Adding another working example:

```
import requests
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict

# Variables
GH_PREFIX = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com"
ORG = "my-user-name"
REPO = "my-repo-name"
BRANCH = "main"
FOLDER = "some-folder"
FILE = "some-file.csv"
URL = GH_PREFIX + "/" + ORG + "/" + REPO + "/" + BRANCH + "/" + FOLDER + "/" + FILE

# Headers setup
headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
headers["Authorization"] = "token " + GITHUB_TOKEN

# Execute and view status
resp = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
if resp.status_code == 200:
   print(resp.content)
else:
   print("Request failed!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the `pygithub`? Very useful for accessing repos, files, pull requests, history, etc. Docs are [here](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html). Here's an example script, which opens a pull request, a new branch off a base branch (you'll need that Access Token, or generate a new one!), and removes a file:

```
from github import Github
my_reviewers = ['usernames', 'of_reviewers']
gh = Github("<token string>")
repo_name = '<my_org>/<my_repo>'
repo = gh.get_repo(repo_name)
default_branch_name = repo.default_branch
base = repo.get_branch(default_branch_name)
new_branch_name = "my_new_branchname"
new_branch = repo.create_git_ref(ref=f'refs/heads/{new_branch_name}',sha=base.commit.sha)
contents = repo.get_contents("some_script_in_repo.sh", ref=new_branch_name)
repo.delete_file(contents.path, "commit message", contents.sha, branch=new_branch_name)
pr = repo.create_pull(
    title="PR to Remove some_script_in_repo.sh",
    body="This is the text in the main body of your pull request",
    head=new_branch_name,
    base=default_branch_name,
)
pr.create_review_request(reviewers=my_reviewers)
```

Hope that helps, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, nowadays, rawgithubusercontent links also work simply with a token, but in python's request case, they need a username:token combination which used to be the norm before github changed it so that only a token is sufficient.

So:

```
https://{token}@raw.githubusercontent.com/username/repo/master/file.csv
```

becomes

```
https://{username}:{token}@raw.githubusercontent.com/username/repo/master/file.csv
```

A sample code for the above would be as follows:

```
from requests import get as rget

res = rget("https://<username>:<token>@raw.githubusercontent.com/<username>/repo/<repo>/file.csv")
with open('file.csv', 'wb+') as f:
        f.write(res.content)
```